# what's the difference between matplotlib.pyplot and matplotlib.figure?

Tags: python, wxpython, matplotlib

I'm just getting into matplotlib.

I see some examples of `matplotlib.pyplot` used, but when integrating matplotlib with wxpython i often see `matplotlib.figure` like

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

...

vboxFigure = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
self.figure = Figure()
self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

t = [1,2,3,4,5]
s = [0,0,0,0,0]

self.axes.plot(t,s, 'b-')
self.canvas = FigureCanvas(panel, -1, self.figure)

vboxFigure.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.EXPAND)
hbox.Add(vboxFigure, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
```

What is the difference between plotting using `matplotlib.figure` and `matplotlib.pyplot`? Can `matplotlib.pyplot` be used in building a wx app?

Comment: Nearly all the examples I could find use `figure` but I had a basic working example with `pyplot` and just wanted to change the axis formatting.  You don't *have* to use `figure` for that; see e.g. http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

The primary difference between using `matplotlib.pyplot` and `matplotlib.figure.Figure` lies in the approach to creating plots and managing the figure objects.

Here's a comparison:

Using `matplotlib.pyplot`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create some data
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

# Plot the data using pyplot
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('X Label')
plt.ylabel('Y Label')
plt.title('Title')
plt.show()
```

Using `matplotlib.figure.Figure`:

```py
import wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None, title='Matplotlib with wxPython', size=(400, 300))
        
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.set_xlabel('X Label')
        self.axes.set_ylabel('Y Label')
        self.axes.set_title('Title')
        
        # Plot the data using Figure and Axes objects
        x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        y = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
        self.axes.plot(x, y)
        
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(panel, -1, self.figure)
        vbox.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.EXPAND)
        
        panel.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Layout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

In the first example, `matplotlib.pyplot` is used to create a plot by directly calling functions like `plt.plot()`, `plt.xlabel()`, `plt.ylabel()`, etc. This approach is simpler and more concise, suitable for interactive plotting and quick scripting.

In the second example, `matplotlib.figure.Figure` is used along with *wxPython* to embed a plot within a *wxPython* application. Here, the figure and axes objects are explicitly created and manipulated, providing more control and customization over the plot's appearance and behavior within the GUI.I hope this helped - I personally would recommend that you use `matplotlib.pyplot` for an easier experience.